# How to send a file to RMA (Records Management Application) to some subfolder?

Tags: records-management, records-center

I am using the OOTB SharePoint RMA (Records Management Application) functionality. I would like to create some custom action which sends the selected documents to the Records Management Application, but not in the dropfolder! I would like to send it to some subfolder. Is that possible programmatically?

I know I need to do something with this url and querystrings. This is what the send file button in the ribbon is doing:

```
http://myCompany.com/sv/ICTDepartment/_layouts/15/SendToOfficialFile.aspx
?ID = rc0001
&Index = beb7b694-9aef-40b2-8910-a6637e138032
&SourceUrl = %2Fsv%2Fsv%5F000124%2FGedeelde%20%20documenten%2FScrum%2DGuide%2DNL%2Epdf
&Source = http%3A%2F%2FMyCompany%2Ecom%2Fsv%2Fsv%5F000124%2FGedeelde%2520%2520documenten%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx%3FInitialTabId%3DRibbon%252EDocument%26VisibilityContext%3DWSSTabPersistence
&InitialTabId = Ribbon%2EDocument
&VisibilityContext = WSSTabPersistence
```

I would like to get the siteName as foldername. I would like to send this file to the record center in the folder "ICTDepartment".